# In R package gt, how do you justify specific text columns?

Tags: html, r, gt

I am trying to print out tables into an html document using R, with the R package gt. I am having trouble how to make the free text parts of the data I am passing into the function justified. How can I change the alignment?

This is my code thus far:

```
tbl_2 <- function(dtframe, ttl, sbttl){




dtbla1 <- gt(dtframe) %>%
    tab_header( title = md(ttl),
                subtitle = md(sbttl) ) %>%
    opt_stylize( style = 6, color = "gray") %>%
    cols_align( align = "center") %>%
    tab_options(  #Title options   
      heading.align = 'center',
      heading.background.color = 'black',
      heading.title.font.size = 30,
      heading.title.font.weight = 'bolder',
      heading.subtitle.font.size = 10,
      heading.subtitle.font.weight = 'normal',) %>%

    tab_options(    # Col Labels options
      column_labels.font.size = 20,
      column_labels.padding = 4)




  return(dtbla1)


}
```

Comment: Did you try `columns` argument in `cols_align` function ?

Comment: If i were to do that, I wouldn't know how to keep the center alignment for the columns which are not text fields.

Comment: I suppose you can call several times `cols_align` function for each alignement

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, used this as code:
    `cols_align( align = "center", columns = where(is.numeric)) %>%`
    `cols_align( align = "auto", columns = where(is.character)) %>%`
It seems to have worked

Comment: Glad it helped ! Good job